# Monitor flickering after power outage

Tags: display, lcd

I have a laptop-to-monitor setup, and after a power outage, the monitor is always flickering on and off (it's really bad at first, then goes down a bit). I have a Samsung SyncMaster 240 monitor.

I'm pretty sure it's just the monitor, because it's fine on the laptop screen. Tried plugging/replugging in everything, and in different sockets, but nothing changes.

I also tried changing the refresh rate of monitor, but the only options were 59/60 HZ and they were about the same.

Comment: Sounds like your monitor is what we in technical circles called *busted*. Unfortunately nothing much to do about it. Toss it or get used to it.

Comment: @Nifle any way to get the power company to pay for it? or is it not worth the time

Comment: Can you be more specific about the symptoms? When you say “flickering on and off” do you mean that it actually turns off then back on and off again? Does it show the OSD each time it flickers? When you say that it “goes down a bit”, do you mean it turns on and off really fast at first then only does it once in a while later? What do you mean by “at first” and “then”, do you mean the first time you turn it on in the morning, and later after it’s been on for a while? Without more specific information, it could be several different things, some of which are fixable, others not.

Comment: @jimmt Local power companies have been known to compensate people for stuff broken in power surges. Whether yours is likely to do that depends on a lot of factors that are specific to where you live. I'd start by complaining to the utility directly. If you don't get a useful response, you should talk to local consumer protection agencies.

Answer (score 1):

some of the possibilities are faulty LCD inverter circuit or SMPS. If you can, try to power up the LCD circuit from an external SMPS and check.